# BASH/ AWK getting stuck in loop?

Tags: bash, awk

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong?  I must be stuck in a loop somewhere's but its not obvious where. (to me)

not getting any error messages just hanging at awk

when I list ipset it is doing what its suppose to do so I'm thinking it never finds the EOF?

```
#! /bin/bash

clear

echo "Removing old list"
rm /config/bogons/bogonsv4.txt
rm /config/bogons/bogonsv6.txt
echo "Updating list from Team Cymru"
curl -o /config/bogons/bogonsv4.txt http://www.team-cymru.org/Services/Bogons/fu
curl -o /config/bogons/bogonsv6.txt http://www.team-cymru.org/Services/Bogons/fu
echo "clearing old bogon tables"
/sbin/ipset flush bogonsv4
/sbin/ipset flush bogonsv6
echo "Updating bogons"
awk '!/^#/ {cmd="/sbin/ipset add bogonsv4 " $1 " >> output";  system(cmd);} end{exit;}' bogonsv4.txt
awk '!/^#/ {cmd="/sbin/ipset add bogonsv6 " $1 " >> output";  system(cmd);} end{exit;}' bogonsv6.txt

exit
```

Comment: Since your script doesn't contain a loop, it seems unlikely it could be stuck in one. Add `set +x` or similar to identify exactly which command you're getting stuck in then [edit] your question to show the result.

Comment: what is this `end{exit;}` clause in awk supposed to do? As is now, it is not doing anything. The end block must be written in uppercase: END. However, exiting there is the default action anyway.

Comment: There's also the "why are you trying to use awk as a shell?" question. Having the shell call awk to call system to call shell to call ipset is just silly.

Comment: awk is calling shell to remove comment lines in the file.  am I able to do that through bash?

Comment: Of course: `while read -r first rest; do echo "$first"; done < <(grep -v '^#' file)`.

Comment: thanks i'll try that and report back.

Comment: got it working Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should debug your code. Temporarily replace the awks by:

```
awk '!/^#/ {cmd="/sbin/ipset add bogonsv4 " $1 " >> output"; print("running:",cmd); system(cmd)}' bogonsv4.txt > errs.txt
awk '!/^#/ {cmd="/sbin/ipset add bogonsv6 " $1 " >> output"; print("running:",cmd); system(cmd)}' bogonsv6.txt >> errs.txt
```

and then examine the `errs.txt` file.